# Is it possible to connect ipc namespeces with docker compose

Tags: namespaces, docker, docker-compose

I need to deploy several containers and connect them to one IPC namespace.
I know that it is possible with:

```
docker run --ipc=""
```

but i have already prepared docker-compose yml file and i am wondering if it is possible to do it with docker-compose instead of `docker run` command?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the development version of `docker-compose` has [support for an ipc keyword](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/docs/compose-file.md#cpu_shares-cpuset-domainname-entrypoint-hostname-ipc-mac_address-mem_limit-memswap_limit-privileged-read_only-restart-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir).

See [commit 1c82359](https://github.com/docker/compose/commit/1c823597bb6c64de9cc320c54f6aa5ca1feff68f) from [PR 1995](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1995).

Comment: Thanks @larsks for help. So i think i will wait for stable release of 1.5.0

Comment: So docker-compose 1.5.0 RC1 has already been released. I will try to check IPC namespaces next week.